# Pyspark RDD collect method shows nothing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong.
So here's simple code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import findspark

findspark.init()

ss = SparkSession.builder.appName('name').getOrCreate()

rd_map = ss.read.text('example.txt')

rd_map.show()
rd_map.rdd.collect()
```

example.txt - is the text file with 4 lines of text. The problem is `rd_map.show()` actually shows resulting dataframe whereas `rd_map.rdd.coolect()` shows nothing. Neither does `.count()` or any other rdd action for that matter.  There's no errors, just standart `Process finished with exit code 0` line.

Comment: `rdd.collect()` actually returns a python list. so simply use `print(rdd.collect())` to print the result

Comment: @blackbishop THANK YOU!